# Printing out $GLOBALS using foreach

Tags: php, html

So I need to print out bunch of pre-defined globals on my page. I try using:

```
<?php foreach ( $GLOBALS as $key => $value ) { ?>
  <dt><label for="<?php echo $key ?>">$key</label></dt>
    <dd><input type="text" name="<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php echo $value ?>" /></dd>
<?php } ?>
```

But that doesn't prints global variables, just some errors instead.
How can I correctly get that list?
I hope you get the idea of what I want.
Thank you!

Comment: This does not produce an endless loop!

Comment: yes actually but it doesn't prints $GLOBAL variables.

Comment: Which errors are shown? Always add the exact messages to your SO questions.

Comment: This code does not give errors, if it did your solution does not fix them. The only difference is that `"$key"` is printed on the label in this case in the question.

Comment: Also some values will be arrays themselves, that will result in some notices!

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the foreach loop entirely:

```
<?php print_r($GLOBALS); ?>
```

I'm not sure of an instance where I would need to print the globals in html quite like that except for debugging.

You are probably coming up on problems in recursion of globals so you could possibly do something like:

```
<?php 
$myGlobals = array();
foreach($GLOBALS as $key => $value ) {
  if ($key == 'GLOBALS') { 
    continue; 
  } else {
  $myGlobals[$key] = $value;
  }
}
foreach ($myGlobals as $key => $value ) { ?>
  <dt><label for="<?php echo $key ?>">$key</label></dt>
  <dd><input type="text" name="<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php echo $value ?>" /></dd>
<?php } ?>
```

That should skip adding the nested GLOBALS array to your array so that you can print all the other keys out without it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

```
<?php foreach ( $GLOBALS as $key => $value ) { ?>
  <dt><label for="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $key ?></label></dt>
    <dd><input type="text" name="<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php echo $value ?>" /></dd>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//shows all used arrays in a page excluding post, get, files, session and
//GLOBALS arrays

function used_arrays() {
    $ark=array_keys($GLOBALS);
    $arr=array();
    foreach ($ark as $key => $value) {
        if($value!= '_GET' and $value!= '_POST' and $value!= '_COOKIE' and $value!= '_FILES' and $value!= 'GLOBALS' )
            array_push($arr,$value);
    }

    $arr2=array();
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $arr2[$value]=$GLOBALS['GLOBALS'][$value];
    }
    echo 'used_arrays<pre>';print_r($arr2);echo '</pre>';
}

//calling
used_arrays();
```